# how to create autocomplete using two different queries?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

code:

```
<input type="text" name="college_name" id="college_name" placeholder="Search By College Name">
<div id="box"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#college_name").keyup(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "autocomplete.php",
                data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#box").show();
                    $("#box").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function selectCollege(val) {
        $("#college_name").val(val);
        college_name = $("#college_name").val();
        location.href = "college.php?college_name=" + college_name;
        $("#box").hide();
    }

    function selectCountry(val) {
        $("#college_name").val(val);
        university_name = $("#college_name").val();
        location.href = "university.php?university_name=" + university_name;
        $("#box").hide();
    }
</script>
```

autocomplete.php

```
<?php
    require_once("dbcontroller.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    if(!empty($_POST['keyword'])) 
    {
        $query ="SELECT college_name,field FROM college where short_name like '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' or college_name like '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' ORDER BY CASE WHEN short_name LIKE '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END limit 100";
        $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
        if(!empty($result)) 
        {
?>
    <ul>
    <a href="#" style="color:#fff;"><li onClick="selectCollege('<?php echo $college["college_name"]; ?>');"><?php echo $college["college_name"]; ?><?php echo $field; ?></li></a>
<?php 
        } 
?>
    </ul>

<?php
    $query ="SELECT university_name,state,university_id FROM university where short_name like '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' or university_name like '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' ORDER BY CASE WHEN short_name LIKE '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' THEN 1 ELSE 2
    END limit 100";
    $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
    if(!empty($result)) 
    {
?>
    <ul>
    <a href="#" style="color:#fff;"><li id="univer-li" onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $university["university_name"]; ?>');"><?php echo $university["university_name"]; ?><?php echo $state; ?></li></a>
<?php 
    } 
?>
    </ul>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

In this code when I write any name inside input field i.e.

```
<input type="text" name="college_name" id="college_name" placeholder="Search By College Name">
```

it show me result like [image]

here you can see it display two scroller but I want single scroller. So, how can I fix this problem ?Please help.

Thank You

Comment: Is there a reason why you've setup your `html` structure to this: `ul > a > li`?

Comment: because I have two different queries i.e table college and table university here I am confuse that how can I use these table to get data in single list ?

Comment: you should really think of using an API and AJAX to do this.

Comment: what wrong with this @matiaslauriti

Comment: You are messing with view and controller. You should avoid completely putting PHP and HTML together, you should do an AJAX call and make an API, really simple. It is cleaner and maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you have `two` list that have `scrolls` because you are echoing two `<ul>` tags.

You can combine all of the `query` results by concatenating all of them like this:

```
<?php
    //@marylyn : Set 1st list
    $sHtmlCollegeTags = '';
    require_once("dbcontroller.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    if(!empty($_POST['keyword'])) 
    {
        $query ="SELECT college_name,field FROM college where short_name like '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' or college_name like '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' ORDER BY CASE WHEN short_name LIKE '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END limit 100";
        $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
        if(!empty($result)) 
        {
?>
    $sHtmlCollegeTags .=
    <a href="#" style="color:#fff;"><li onClick="selectCollege('<?php echo $college["college_name"]; ?>');"><?php echo $college["college_name"]; ?><?php echo $field; ?></li></a>
<?php 
        } 
?>
    </ul>

<?php
    //@marylyn : Set 2nd list
    $sHtmlUnivTags = '';
    $query ="SELECT university_name,state,university_id FROM university where short_name like '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' or university_name like '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' ORDER BY CASE WHEN short_name LIKE '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' THEN 1 ELSE 2
    END limit 100";
    $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
    if(!empty($result)) 
    {
?>
    $sHtmlUnivTags .= 
    <a href="#" style="color:#fff;"><li id="univer-li" onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $university["university_name"]; ?>');"><?php echo $university["university_name"]; ?><?php echo $state; ?></li></a>
<?php
    } 
?>
<?php 
    }
?>


<?php 
    // @marylyn : Concatenate both $sHtmlCollegeTags and $sHtmlUnivTags
    echo '<ul>' . $sHtmlCollegeTags . $sHtmlUnivTags . '</ul>';
?>
```